# How do I make my grid template mobile-friendly?

Tags: html, css

Right, I have a grid template lay out for my website where, on the desktop version, there are two columns. As this is shrunken down to a mobile version I would like this to be one column which fills the whole width of the device.

How would I go about doing this?

Here is the code below.

Thanks.

```css
.grid{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
    /*grid-template-rows: repeat(6, 1fr);*/
    grid-template-rows:auto;
    grid-template-areas: 
    "Title                Content-Upper" 
    "Title              Content-Lower";
    grid-gap: 20px;
}

.Title{
    grid-area: Title;
  
}

.Content-Upper{
    grid-area: Content;
    
}

.Content-Lower{
    grid-area: Content;
    border-style: solid 2px black;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
            <div class="Title">
                <div class="wrap__center">
                    <h1 style="font-size: 43px;" class="header__main" ><span id="">Title</span></h1>
                </div>
            </div>
            <a href="#" class="Content content-update-ceo">
                <h1 class="header__main">Uper Column</h1>
            </a>
            <a href="" class="Content content-update-covid">
                <h1 class="header__main" style="width: 50%;">Lower Column</h1>
            </a>
        </div>
```

Comment: you need to use `media query` and change your grid system at several breakpoints till you reach the desired result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grid systems can be affected with [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries) just like any other CSS property. By default, you can set up a grid with one column, and then expand it to two columns when the viewport is wide enough. Note the changes to the `grid-template-area` definitions as well.

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  /* one column with three rows for mobile */
  grid-template-columns: auto;
  grid-template-rows: auto auto auto;
  grid-template-areas:
    "Title"
    "Content-Upper"
    "Content-Lower";
  grid-gap: 20px;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .grid {
    /* two columns with two rows for tablet and up */
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: auto auto;
    grid-template-areas:
      "Title Content-Upper"
      "Title Content-Lower";
    grid-gap: 20px;
  }
}
.Title {
  grid-area: Title;
}
.Content-Upper {
  grid-area: Content;
}
.Content-Lower {
  grid-area: Content;
  border-style: solid 2px black;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="Title">
    <div class="wrap__center">
      <h1 style="font-size: 43px;" class="header__main"><span id="">Title</span></h1>
    </div>
  </div>
  <a href="#" class="Content content-update-ceo">
    <h1 class="header__main">Uper Column</h1>
  </a>
  <a href="" class="Content content-update-covid">
    <h1 class="header__main" style="width: 50%;">Lower Column</h1>
  </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

```
      @media screen and (max-width: 414px) {
       .grid{
          grid-template-columns: repeat(1, 1fr);
        } 
      }
```

It's as easy as that ;)

Comment: Don't really need the repeat for 1 item :)

Comment: This answer could be improved with an explanation.

Comment: It's also an incorrect answer. Unless the `grid-template-areas` property is also overwritten, it will generate an additional implicit grid track for the extra column, and the content will still be two columns.

Comment: Well, I saw that he knows about Grid that's why I didn't explain :)

Comment: The purpose of Stack Overflow is for answers to be helpful for future readers, not just the author of the question. And the author's experience level with CSS grid (and their gender) shouldn't be assumed.

Comment: Thanks peoples, you're life savers :) I've marked Seans.

Comment: Quick question, how do I have the height of the boxed to the contents, they're just strips at the moment with the contents spilling out?